# How to fade curves of an animated gif in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animated-gif

I have a gif but i want to fade the curves plotted. I have read [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111040/how-to-change-color-of-plotted-curves-when-using-animations-in-python-matplotlib) but still I need help. At the moment all curves are the same:

[image]

This code makes the gif for me:

```
import matplotlib
import imageio
def plot_for_offset(time, value):
    ims = []
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,2.5))
    for t, v in zip (time, value):
        axs.plot(t, v, lw=1.0, color='k')
        # Used to return the plot as an image rray
        fig.canvas.draw()       # draw the canvas, cache the renderer
        image = np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype='uint8')
        image  = image.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))
        ims.append(image)
    return ims
kwargs_write = {'fps':1.0, 'quantizer':'nq'}

import numpy as np                              
time = np.array([[0., 1., 2.], [0., 1., 2.], [0., 1., 2.]])
value = np.array([[0., 10., 20.], [20., 10., 0.], [10., 10., 10.]])
imageio.mimsave('animation.gif', plot_for_offset(time, value), fps=1.0)
```

Now, I want to fade the curves poped up in the past. I very much appreciate any help.

Comment: As the question reads now, I can't really tell what the exact problem is. there seems to be non-essential code in your example (e.g. `kwargs_write`, `set_xlim`, `set_ylim`). Can you make it even simpler isolating the issue?

Comment: Dear @LudvigH, I want a gif in which lines show up sequential and when a new line comes, previous ones get fade or grey. If you look at my gif it has three lines. Each one is coming as a snapshot. When the second comes, I want to faded out the first one or when the third one comes, I want  to fade out first two lines.

Comment: Create multiple frames, where each frame the fading line gets coloured a brighter grey until it's white (assuming a white background); or adjust the alpha channel per frame of the fading line until it's fully transparent. Do the same for each of the lines. That will give quite a few frames (depending on how or slow you want the fading to be), but that is the nature of the thing.

Comment: Side note: while widely supported, an animated gif doesn't tend to be the most efficient file format for animated images; so if you end up with a large file, see if there's a more suitable format.

Comment: Dear @9769953, thanks for your hints. I do appreciate your time. Have you any idea how to implement your hints in python? My programming background is not mature enough to implement such complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by changing the transparency `alpha` of your plot at each frame of your animation.

See example below using the FuncAnimation function from matplotlib (doc [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html)):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

time = np.array([[0., 1., 2.], [0., 1., 2.], [0., 1., 2.],[0, 1, 2],[0, 1, 2]])
value =np.array([[0., 10., 20.], [20., 10., 0.], [10., 10., 10.],[2, 2 ,2],[7, 14, 18]])
fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,2.5))
ln=[plt.plot(time[i], value[i], lw=2.0, color='k',alpha=i==0) for i in range(len(time))]
ln=[ln[i][0] for i in range(len(time))]
axs.set_xlim(0, 2)
axs.set_ylim(0, 20)
step=5

def update(frame):

    if frame<=(len(ln)*step)-1: # generalize to N curves
      ln[frame//step].set_alpha(1)
      [ln[i].set_alpha(0) for i in range(frame//step+1, len(ln))]
      [ln[i].set_alpha(1/(frame-(i+1)*step+1)) for i in range(frame//step)]
    else:
      [ln[i].set_alpha(1/(frame-(i+1)*step+1)) for i in range(len(ln)-1)]
    return ln

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=10*step,blit=True)
```

And the output gives:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and response. There is only one issue, what if I have tens of lines rather than three? should I repeat the update function for as much as lines I have? At the moment you have three conditions but what if I have tens of lines?

Comment: It's fairly straightforward to generalize it to `N` curves. See edit of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried the code but when I change the length of `time` and `value`. For example make it: `time = np.array([[0., 1., 2.], [0., 1., 2.]])` and `value =np.array([[0., 10., 20.], [20., 10., 0.]])` or add another row to them. Then, the code does not work.

Comment: See edit for the generalized solution